# Outlook custom plugin code not working as expected (Downlaod Email attachment)

Tags: outlook

I am tring to save attachemnt from a incoming mail in outllok. This is my code. My issue is it  downloads correctly when email arrives(when my laptop is open), but this mail is scheduled everyday at 6:00 AM, I open my laptop at 9 and mail is already present and it is not downloading as expected?Do i need to do anything with code?

```
const string destinationDirectory = @"\\prod_data\Service Now\";

            Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer()
                 .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook
                 .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
            Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
            inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
            try
            {
                foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
                {
                    newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;

                    if (newEmail != null)
                    {
                        if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail
                               .Attachments.Count; i++)
                            {

                                if (newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName.Contains( "LogicView Issue Report"))
                                {

                                    newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(destinationDirectory +
                                        newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any errors? When do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out the [MarkForDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866920(v=office.15).aspx) property value. It returns an OlRemoteStatus constant that determines the status of an item once it is received by a remote user. For example:

```
Sub DownloadItems()
  Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
  Dim obj As Object  
  Dim i As Integer 
  Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  'Loop all items in the Inbox folder  
  For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count  
    Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i)  
   'Verify if the state of the item is olHeaderOnly  
   If obj.DownloadState = olHeaderOnly Then  
     MsgBox ("This item has not been fully downloaded.")  
    'Mark the item to be downloaded.  
    obj.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload  
  End If  
  Next  
End Sub
```

You can use the [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863925(v=office.15).aspx) method of the SyncObject class to begin synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Application.NewMail` event - it fires only when Outlook is running at the time the email is received by the Exchange server.

Use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder (`Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`) - it will fire when the email downloaded to the cached store when Outlook synchronizes the Inbox folder (assuming you are using cached mode). If Outlook is online, no events will fire. In that case, you can use `Items.Find/FindNext` to process all unread messages `([Unread] = 'true'`).

```
//declare on the global/class level to make sure 
//it does not get garbage collected
private Outlook.Items inBoxItems;
...
//in your addin startup code
inBoxItems = inBox.Items
inBoxItems.ItemAdd += inboxItemsItemAdd;
...
private void inboxItemsItemAdd(object item)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a smaple code of Items.ItemAdd?That would be helpful